# Convert first row of dataframes (into a list) in a new column and delete the first rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe, row

I have got a list composed by 25 dataframes and I would like to convert the first rows into a column for each dataframe and delete the first rows.

Here an example of two of my dataframes contained into the list:

```
[[24]]
                    V1      V2      V3    V4                  V5
1                85003      NA                                  
2  01/10/1979 09:00:00 153.392  50 (G)  calc 12/09/1980 07:15:00
3  01/10/1980 09:00:00 143.276  50 (G)  calc 07/02/1981 14:00:00
4  01/10/1981 09:00:00 149.138 200 (V)  calc 20/11/1981 05:00:00
[...]

[[25]]
                    V1      V2      V3    V4                  V5
1                94001      NA                                  
2  01/10/1972 09:00:00  77.277 200 (V)  calc 02/12/1972 04:15:00
3  01/10/1973 09:00:00  94.340 200 (V)  calc 19/01/1974 13:45:00
4  01/10/1974 09:00:00 116.410 200 (V)  calc 08/12/1974 01:30:00
[....]
```

My final output should be as follows:

```
[[24]]
                    V1      V2      V3    V4                  V5   V6
1  01/10/1979 09:00:00 153.392  50 (G)  calc 12/09/1980 07:15:00   85003
2  01/10/1980 09:00:00 143.276  50 (G)  calc 07/02/1981 14:00:00   85003
3  01/10/1981 09:00:00 149.138 200 (V)  calc 20/11/1981 05:00:00   85003
[...]

[[25]]
                    V1      V2      V3    V4                  V5  V6
1  01/10/1972 09:00:00  77.277 200 (V)  calc 02/12/1972 04:15:00  94001
2  01/10/1973 09:00:00  94.340 200 (V)  calc 19/01/1974 13:45:00  94001
3  01/10/1974 09:00:00 116.410 200 (V)  calc 08/12/1974 01:30:00  94001
[....]
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `lapply`

```
lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) transform(x, V6 = V1[1])[-1,])
```